# Caption Package Causing Errors

Tags: packages

Consider the following MWE, named `scratchTex.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

When I enter the command `pdflatex scratchTex.tex`, I get

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 45, version
               `2013/05/01' of package caption3,
               but only version
               `2009/10/09 v3.1k caption3 kernel (AR)'
               is available.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.202 \caption@ifamsclass
                         {%
?
```

I've search all files in the `caption` folder in my repository and none contain the string "ifamsclass".  Should I download and install the latest `caption` class?

Comment: Are you using TeX Live? It's currently frozen until the 2015 release becomes available. You can [grab an up-to-date copy from CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption): [`caption3.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption3.dtx) (the compile the `.dtx` to produce a `.sty`).

Comment: You probably have a rogue version of `caption3.sty` somewhere.. If you look in the `.log` file, you can easily see where the packages are found on your system. Please, add it, if you can't spot the issue.

Comment: As mentioned, there could be an old version laying around. Or not. Nobody knows. I vote to close as unclear.